# Can anyone help me identify this Anime piece?

Tags: merchandise

I just picked this piece up and know NOTHING about it except its a Guyver. I'm thinking its a mold. I'm really interested in finding out more about it. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's part of a vinyl kit for Guyver II:

[image: Just the head]

Comment: Thanks! Do you think its a mold or some sort of prop?

Comment: It's a vinyl model kit (probably third party) for hobbyists. Basically what is it you get a garage kit with pieces that are uncolored and you color them and customize it the way you want (resin kit and gunpla models are along the same lines as this).

Comment: Can you tell me if its missing pieces? Do you have any idea what it's worth?
Thanks again.

Comment: It's probably just the head and not much. [This site](http://homemedia4u.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=162_211&products_id=4310&osCsid=vk8s3achjc41bgq5cq5lk5fun3) has it on sale for about 16 euros.